# Php construct link

Tags: php

```
$term_link = add_query_arg( array('wpvdeliver-to' => $term->slug) );
```

As you can see the above code will output ?wpvdeliver-to=XXXX, so i want to add

```
custom-result/
```

in front of it to make it output

```
custom-result/?wpvdeliver-to=XXXX
```

How is it possible, as i cannot directly add the word in front the add_query, and if i add after the word array it will be

```
?custom-result/wpvdeliver-to=XXXX
```

instead.

Comment: Use `custom-result/` as third parameter for `add_query_arg`.

Comment: @u_mulder can you elaborate more as i really php 0 level thanks